# Communication with Apple failed error

Tags: ios, entitlements, applepay

While trying to implement Apple Pay under "Capabilities" tab, when “Add the Apple Pay identifiers” entitlement to your App ID” is being processed, failure results with message: "Communication with Apple failed."

There is no error code or identifier.

Xcode Ver. 7.3.1
paid dev account

Comment: Which version of Xcode are you running?

Comment: And do you have a paid developer account?

Comment: Make sure your provisioning profiles are valid and not expired.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your provisioning profiles are valid and not expired.

You can confirm from :

> Xcode -> Preferences -> Account -> Select Apple ID -> View Details ->
>   Check Provisioning profiles expiration date.

Comment: not sure if it was this, or creating a Mac Development profile, or running rvm osx-ssl-certs update all but you've saved me! Thank you!